# Orient a Knot Diagram

Tags: knots

I need some help to orient a diagram knot
For example if I have the diagram  `KnotData["Trefoil,"KnotDiagram"]`

How can I orient the diagram?

I have tried to find a command in Wolfram that assigns an orientation to the knot, but I still can't find it, the closest I have found is the `DirectedEdge` command.

Does anyone know how I could orient the diagram of a knot or can you give me an idea on which commands to use?

Comment: do you get what you need using `KnotData["Trefoil", "KnotDiagram"] /. Line -> Arrow`  and/or `KnotData["Trefoil", "KnotDiagram"] /. Line -> (Arrow@*Reverse)`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace `Line`s with `Arrow`s:

```
KnotData["Trefoil", "KnotDiagram"] /. Line -> Arrow
```

[image]

To reverse the direction of arrows use

```
KnotData["Trefoil", "KnotDiagram"] /. Line -> (Arrow @* Reverse)
```

[image]